# Mac hard restart, on restart VS Code says "There are no active source control providers". How to fix git.path?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

My Mac froze while VS Code was open and upon restart and opening VS Code it appears that I no longer have git configured. I checked the path where my git is located using "where git" in terminal and it reports: **usr/local/bin/git**

I manually added the setting:

```
"git.path": "usr/local/bin/git"
```

there in "User Settings", but it still reports "There are no active source control providers". What am I doing wrong?

[image]

When I click "Replace in Settings" I get an error message but there are no warnings or errors showing in settings:

[image]

Update: (1) There was an error in my user settings I didn't see at first. (2) As @esqew pointed out, I was missing the leading "/" in the path in user settings. Correcting those issues and doing a "Reload Window" command fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you possibly missing a leading slash `/` in your path…? There’s a huge difference between what you’ve got now and `/usr/local/bin/git`.

Comment: That was it. I added the forward slash there and then did a "Reload Window" and git appears to be back. However, git.path in "Default Settings" is still null. Is that expected?